# Ability to move app to SD is broken

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've looked around on here and found a few posts related to allowing app to SD functionality, but [I still think] I've got things set up correctly.  The app asks some users if they'd like to install the app to SD on update/initial install, but won't allow them to move it to the SD card later.  On the phone I use (Android 2.2.1), I have the same issue.  On one of my test phones (Android 2.2), I can move it to SD and back to the phone just fine.

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.badwaterstudios.ProfanityCandy"
    android:versionCode="18"
    android:versionName="2.1.2"
    android:name="ProfanityCandy"
    android:installLocation="auto" > <!-- SDK 8+ only, allows install to SD -->

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason why the application can't be moved to the SD card is if you have **copy protection** turned **on** in the publishing options(seen while publishing/updating your app).  Turn this off to allow moving app to the SD card.

Also see the article at http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html about **Applications That Should NOT Install on External Storage**

Comment: Ah, yeah--I was using the licensing framework for the Pro version, and had since turned off the copy protection there but not in the free version (no idea why I even had it there in the first place on that one).  That did the trick--thanks for the suggestion and the reference!